# rvest: css / xpath from SelectorGadget not working

Tags: css, xpath, rvest

I want to extract all download links for txt-files from this page: https://www.bundestag.de/dokumente/protokolle/plenarprotokolle/plenarprotokolle. To do so, I tried [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) and selected the following:

[image]

With this information I wrote this code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

protokolle <- 
  read_html("https://www.bundestag.de/dokumente/protokolle/plenarprotokolle/plenarprotokolle")

txts <- 
  protokolle %>% 
  html_nodes(".bt-link-dokument")
```

The result is the same if I try

```
txts <- 
  protokolle %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "bt-link-dokument", " " ))]')
```

For a reason I do not understand, `txts` contains only `{xml_nodeset (0)}`. Any ideas on what went wrong?

Comment: the links are `//a[starts-with(@title, 'TXT')]` but I can't help with RVest, just xpath

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but isn't working either. Still `{xml_nodeset (0)}`. :/